# Insert a subpage with text in my actual html

Tags: html, frame

I have this code:

```
<div align="justify">
    <table width="552" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Name of this article</h1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text_dreapta">On March 22, 2017, in <a href="page_1.html" title="See all articles from Page 1" class="external" rel="category tag">Marketing</a>, by My Name</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="text_obisnuit2">HERE TO INSERT A SUBPAGE.HTML (that has some html text content) </p>
```

I have to insert a subpage.html, that has some content, in this div. So, not a just a simple link, but a link that will show the content of subpage.html

Can anyone help me?

I had try, but not workin:

```
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
    <frame src="manual.htm">
    <frameset  cols="50%,50%">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: [<iframe>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Or better yet [From object to iframe — other embedding technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies)

Comment: Just a side note: iframes are dead (for page layouting) for a long time. The exchange of the content is usually done (in plain html) by switching the whole page. So link to another page "b", which has its own head, body, full content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`iframe`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) can help you:

```
<iframe src="otherHTML.html"></iframe>
```

Based from your codes

```
<div align="justify">
    <table width="552" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><h1 class="den_articol" itemprop="name">Name of this article</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text_dreapta">On March 22, 2017, in <a href="page_1.html" title="See all articles from Page 1" class="external" rel="category tag">Marketing</a>, by My Name</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <iframe src="otherHTML.html" class="text_obisnuit2">subpage</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: hello Carl, good answer. If I want to add some size to the iframe, how can I do this on you code?

Comment: Add a `height` and/or `width` attribute to the `<iframe>`

Comment: Or you can style it using css

Comment: As @malejpavouk said in the comment, `iframe` is now rarely used nowadays.

Comment: thank you, Carl . `<iframe src="manual.htm" class="text_obisnuit2" width="700" height="1200" frameBorder="0">subpage</iframe>`

Comment: so, if it is rarely used nowadays, what can I use instead?

Comment: `<embed src="manual.htm" width="700" height="1200"" />`

or as an much better alternative you can use 

`<object data="manual.htm" width="700" height="1200" type="text/html"></object>`